# Node memory leak with nuxt 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

Ok so my app is a bit large and all of the sudden I started to experience some crashes, I thought it was something random that would only happen once.

Once it started to happen more times (it crashes after a couple minutes of developing, 20 to 30 minutes maybe) I didn't knew what the hell it could be, it was then I discovered it was a memory leak.

Well at first I had  some global mixins that I took down and transformed in a prototype so that they would only get included once, that didn't solve the problem.

I updated to nuxt 2 since I knew it would handle this issues better, but that didn't solve it nor gave more information of where could it be and what was triggering it.

I've had this issue for a while and no one seems to be able to point me in the right direction and I don't know where to start or what to do to find the culprit, I hope someone has encountered a similar issue and can point me in the right direction.

The error dump I get is the following:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[87277:0x103800000]  6485776 ms: Mark-sweep 1349.3 (1457.6) -> 1349.3 (1457.6) MB, 922.3 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested
[87277:0x103800000]  6486970 ms: Mark-sweep 1349.3 (1457.6) -> 1349.3 (1426.1) MB, 1191.0 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
[87277:0x103800000]  6488029 ms: Mark-sweep 1349.3 (1426.1) -> 1349.3 (1426.1) MB, 1058.7 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0xd2f89325879 <JSObject>
    1: createWriteReq(aka createWriteReq) [net.js:797] [bytecode=0xd2f1f199659 offset=111](this=0xd2f8ce022d1 <undefined>,req=0xd2f39a113c9 <WriteWrap map = 0xd2fd94eb3a1>,handle=0xd2f42ca3499 <TCP map = 0xd2f3d1578c1>,data=0xd2f39a11241 <Very long string[652355]>,encoding=0xd2f893358e9 <String[4]: utf8>)
    2: _writeGeneric [net.js:760] [bytecode=0xd2f1f198401 offset=395](this=0xd2fd0188f41 <So...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/Users/joaopetinga/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node]
 2: node::FatalException(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Message>) [/Users/joaopetinga/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node]
 3: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/Users/joaopetinga/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/Users/joaopetinga/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node]
 5: v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::ConsString>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/Users/joaopetinga/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node]
 6: v8::String::WriteUtf8(char*, int, int*, int) const [/Users/joaopetinga/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node]
 7: node::StringBytes::Write(v8::Isolate*, char*, unsigned long, v8::Local<v8::Value>, node::encoding, int*) [/Users/joaopetinga/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node]
 8: int node::StreamBase::WriteString<(node::encoding)1>(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/Users/joaopetinga/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node]
 9: void node::StreamBase::JSMethod<node::LibuvStreamWrap, &(int node::StreamBase::WriteString<(node::encoding)1>(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&))>(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/Users/joaopetinga/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node]
10: v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)) [/Users/joaopetinga/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node]
11: v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<false>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) [/Users/joaopetinga/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node]
12: v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCall(v8::internal::BuiltinArguments, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/Users/joaopetinga/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node]
13: 0x50d80d842fd
Abort trap: 6
```

I've read this multiple times but I can't extract any useful information (I don't know what to look for)
I really need some help on this one.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check the browser's dev tools to inspect the memory usage? For Chrome: Open dev tools, select "Memory" tab und click "Take heap snapshot" - you're then able to discover the biggest objects/arrays/etc. which will guide you on how to solve the leak.

Comment: @BennettDams I did that but all I see is the GC actually reducing the memory consumption, this happens so randomly that I can't predict when I should start recording a snapshot

Comment: I can confirm that this is the issue I am having, and I have no clue how to solve it. In addition - I am now afraid that this might happen in production! What the hell? :(

Comment: @Rouz although I've never got to understand what was the exact culprit I learned a couple of things that could help track down whats causing it:

1) disable plugis one by one and see if the issue goes away
2) treat edge cases: do not use any global event listeners, avoid global mixins and others
3) check if you're not using <keep-alive> in a large amount
4) make sure that nuxt is up-to-date, that seemed to have a positive effect on my . issue